# Why is my SQL server memory table files growing

Tags: sql-server, memory-table

I added a memory filegroup and a file to an existing database. After a few minutes the file expanded to 17GB.

Then I added a couple of more files, and they are slowly growing as well. Today they are 700MB and 536MB. Thats a 100% growth since yesterday.

My question is: Why is this happening? I have not added any memory tables, and the Service Broker is disabled.

Any clues?

Comment: Did you create memory optimized tables .Which version of SQL you are on.Post some sample schema,table definition

Comment: I have not added any memory tables. The version is 2014 SP1. It happends with all databases so I'm not really looking for a solution, but an explanation :)